# pandas dataframe get rows based on matched strings in cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data frame

```
+-----+----------------+--------+---------+
|     |       A        |     B  |    C    |
+-----+----------------+--------+---------+
| 0   | hello@me.com   | 2.0    | Hello   |
| 1   | you@you.com    | 3.0    | World   |
| 2   | us@world.com   | hi     | holiday |
+-----+----------------+--------+---------+
```

How can I get all the rows where `re.compile([Hh](i|ello))` would match in a cell? That is, from the above example, I would like to get the following output:

```
+-----+----------------+--------+---------+
|     |       A        |    B   |    C    |
+-----+----------------+--------+---------+
| 0   | hello@me.com   | 2.0    | Hello   |
| 2   | us@world.com   | hi     | holiday |
+-----+----------------+--------+---------+
```

I am not able to get a solution for this. And help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [findall](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) function which takes regular expressions.

```
msk = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.findall(r'[Hh](i|ello)')).any(axis=1)
df[msk]

+---|------------|------|---------+
|   |     A      |  B   |    C    |
+---|------------|------|---------+
| 0 |hello@me.com|  2   |  Hello  |
| 2 |us@world.com|  hi  | holiday |
+---|------------|------|---------+
```

`any(axis=1)` will check if any of the columns in a given row are true.  So `msk` is a single column of True/False values indicating whether or not the regular expression was found in that row.

Comment: thank you, this is what I used in the end. (and apologies for accepting that late!)

Answer (score 3):

Using `stack` to avoid `apply`

```
df.loc[df.stack().str.match(r'[Hh](i|ello)').unstack().any(1)]
```

[image]

Using `match` generates a future warning.  The warning is consistant with what we are doing, so that's good.  However, `findall` accomplishes the same thing

```
df.loc[df.stack().str.findall(r'[Hh](i|ello)').unstack().any(1)]
```